# Unable to Update in Firebase using react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update the firebase table using the react native and instead of updating new entry is being inserted which i dont want. Code is:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users1').child(this.props.navigation.state.params.keyis).set({email:this.state.email,password:this.state.password})
```

this.props.navigation.state.params.keyis- This contains the unique id for each row present to update. and email, password are the fields. Using this I need to update it. My key is changing after i submit so insert is happening instead of update and hence not able to compare it with the existing key. This variable comes up from previous page and is stored like this:

```
<TextInput style={{marginTop:20, height:40, borderColor:'gray', borderWidth:1}} onChangeText={keyis=>this.setState({keyis})} value={this.state.keyis}/>
```

This is the structure of database:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `set` you need to use `update`. something like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users1').child(this.props.navigation.state.params.keyis).update({email:this.state.email,password:this.state.password})
```

Comment: firebase.database().ref('/users1').update({email:this.state.email,password:this.state.password})

Try this and see what happens. It should search for the email and update accordingly

Comment: new entry is passed without any unique id. The thing is after new record is inserted mistakenly and i edit that then update is happening with the query I have given above, so all the database keys and this key i need to compare it and then update should happen.

Comment: He wants the same node to be updated. `push()` will generated new DB ID each time. I had asked @ChintanBhuta to change the path with user UID. So that it remains constant and updates only required data. I'm not a JavaScript expert yet but yes that's what he wants to do.